# C++ Client on UDP with multithreading in Boost Asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, udp, client-server, boost-asio

Im trying to make the client and server using UDP. I need two threeds in client: one for sending one message every 50 milliseconds and second for sending some managing messages. After around 5-6 minutes of work, one of them stops. But i dont know why? Im using sniffer (Wireshark) to control the packets, and didnt notice anything unusual.

Here is my code client:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <boost/asio.hpp> 
#include <boost/thread.hpp> 
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

class UDP_Client
{
private:
    boost::asio::io_service service;
    udp::endpoint endPoint;
    std::string message;

public:
    UDP_Client() {}

    UDP_Client(std::string host, int port)
    {
        endPoint = udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(host), port);
    }

    ~UDP_Client() {}


    static std::string transformToCharCodes(std::string msg)
    {
        std::string outMess;
        for(int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++)
        {
            char letter = msg[i];
            outMess += static_cast<char>(atoi(&letter));
        }
        return outMess;
    }


    void cyclicInterrogation()
    {
        int const PORT = 50000;
        try
        {
            while(true) {
                std::string messageBuffer = message;

                udp::socket socket(service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), PORT));

                std::string outMess = transformToCharCodes(messageBuffer);

                socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(outMess), endPoint);

                char recievedBuffer[1024];
                udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
                boost::system::error_code error;
                int lenght = socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recievedBuffer), sender_endpoint, 0, error);

                if(error && error != boost::asio::error::message_size) {
                    throw boost::system::system_error(error);
                }

                std::string copy(recievedBuffer, lenght);
                std::cout << "Recieved: ";
                for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
                {
                    std::cout << static_cast<int>(recievedBuffer[i]) << " ";
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;

                socket.close();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
            }
        }
        catch(std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
            system("pause");
        }
    }

    void autoSending()
    {
        int const PORT = 50001;
        while(true) {
            std::string msgArray[4] = {"456", "5", "", "5"};

            for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(msgArray) / sizeof(msgArray[0]); i++)
            {
                sendMessage(msgArray[i], PORT);
                boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(500));
            }
        }
    }

    void userInputSendnig()
    {
        int const PORT = 50002;
        while(true)
        {
            getline(std::cin, message);
            sendMessage(message, PORT);
        }
    }

    void sendMessage(std::string msg, int port)
    {
        std::string messageBuffer;
        char recievedBuffer[1024];

        message = messageBuffer = msg;
        udp::socket sock(service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port));

        std::string outMess = transformToCharCodes(messageBuffer);

        sock.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(outMess), endPoint);

        udp::endpoint sender_ep;
        boost::system::error_code error;
        sock.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recievedBuffer), sender_ep, 0, error);

        if(error && error != boost::asio::error::message_size) {
            throw boost::system::system_error(error);
        }

        sock.close();
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    std::string const IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.0.20";
    int const PORT = 2000;

    UDP_Client client(IP_ADDRESS, PORT);

    boost::thread thread1(boost::bind(&UDP_Client::cyclicInterrogation, &client));

    boost::thread thread2(boost::bind(&UDP_Client::autoSending, &client));
    boost::thread thread3(boost::bind(&UDP_Client::userInputSendnig, &client));

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();
}
```

Code of server:

```
#include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/udp.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

boost::asio::io_service service;

void handle_connections()
{
    try
    {
        char buff[1024];
        udp::socket sock(service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 2000));
        while(true)
        {
            udp::endpoint sender_ep;
            //sender_ep.address(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.0.20"));
            int length = sock.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buff), sender_ep);
            std::string msg(buff, length);
            sock.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(msg), sender_ep);
            std::cout << "Recieved from client: " << msg << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        system("pause");
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    handle_connections();
}
```

I don't know what i did wrong ...